# How to avoid fread() importing date info as IDate?

Tags: r, fwrite, fread

I initially wrote a script that does calculation running through ~70k iterations, I was using rbind to 'stitch' the outcomes together (1 iteration can result in outcome with 0 to many rows, so I don't think pre-allocating the output makes sense). To speed things up I've split this into 4 separate scripts that each handle 25% of the iterations in separate sessions and write their solutions (each between 150k-400k rows) to csv, which are all read back into a single script to bind the solutions together

I'm having a problem with one of the columns though - it contains a date, in the csv they're stored as "dd-mm-yy" ...  **Scripts 1, 2 & 4 read in as anticipated - they're stored as 'character' type which is fine by me. However script 3 reads in the date column as an IDate and adds "00" at the front of the string**

The rbind doesn't like having different data types, I can 'make it work' by including *colClasses = c(DATE = "character")* in the fread for file 3, however I'd much rather understand WHY it is occurring and assume I can probably adjust something at the fwrite stage?

Comment: Looks like recent versions of `fread` automatically guess date formats - https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/data.table/versions/1.14.0/topics/fread - "*bit64::integer64, IDate, and POSIXct types are also detected and read directly without needing to read as character before converting.* The solution appears to be to force it manually with `colClasses=` as you suggest. I can't see any other argument you could change in the documentation.

Comment: Thanks for the response!  The confusing part is that only 1 of the 4 read in that manner, even though all of the data was collected/calculated/written in the same way...

Comment: What exactly is the difference would be nice to know. I suspect there are badly formatted dates in most files except for the one that converted everything to `IDate`. I.e. there will be one value that is `'Unknown'` or `32-01-2000` or something that either can't be converted to a date or is invalid. You'd need to dig through the csvs to be absolutely sure.

Comment: I would like to know that too!  I concur with your suspicion, I'll have a play with the date formatting in the calculation scripts before they fwrite and see if that helps...

Comment: see https://stackoverflow.com/a/72188681/13513328

Answer (score 1):

It appears the issue lay in the date format of the original data, everything worked by passing the data through as.Date before writing to the csv files

Thanks to @thelatemail for pointing out: "recent versions of fread automatically guess date formats - https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/data.table/versions/1.14.0/topics/fread - "bit64::integer64, IDate, and POSIXct types are also detected and read directly without needing to read as character before converting."

I'm still not 100% sure why only 1 of 4 was read as date while the others as character, but my hypothesis is that the "dd-mm-yy" format is ambiguous for the fread to interpret so should be avoided if possible

Answer (score 0):

For now, you can do this with:

```
options(datatable.old.fread.datetime.character=T)
```

In the [NEWS file](https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/blob/master/NEWS.md) for the data.table package under "data.table v1.14.0 (21 Feb 2021)" it says "As before, the migration option datatable.old.fread.datetime.character can still be set to TRUE to revert to the old character behavior. This migration option is temporary and will be removed in the near future."

But as of version 1.14.8 (the current latest non-dev version) this option still works.

Reading dates as character will make data.table::fread() slower and make memory usage higher, but if you really need to do it there is a way.